# Why does strtotime() get confused about timezones (instead of ignoring them), and what's the solution?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, timezone, strtotime

I have this:

```
var_dump(strtotime('1718-11-30 00:00:12+01:12:12'));
var_dump(strtotime('1718-11-30 00:00:12'));
```

I expect:

```
int(-7923575520)
int(-7923575520)
```

I get:

```
bool(false)
int(-7923575520)
```

It gets confused whenever "timezone" syntax is included, but that's simply how the strings I deal with look. (They come from my database.)

I know that strtotime doesn't "handle" timezones, but why not just ignore them, then?

Of course, I could make a regexp replace to remove the "+" and anything to the right of it, but that feels extremely hackish and fragile. What is the more solid and correct solution?

And yes, I'm aware of the `DateTimeImmutable` stuff, which I use elsewhere, but in this case, I have to deal with Unix timestamps. Not because I like them, but because various functions and situations expect and require them.

At first, I assumed that the year was too far back in history or something, but clearly it knows how to do "minus" timestamps, so that's not an issue.

Comment: `strtotime()` doesn't get "confused" because you're using timezones. It just don't handle the format `+01:12:12` (with the seconds). Usually, timezone diffs are in hours and minutes, without seconds: `+01:12`. As far as I know, there's no timezone where the diff includes seconds?

Comment: @M.Eriksson There must be, because that's what PostgreSQL does.

Comment: However, you are right about `strtotime` understanding the timezone stuff when there's no seconds part. I just tried it.

Comment: PostgreSQL keeps reverting back to the format with the seconds, no matter what I do. Sigh.